# Enter insert mode indented in VIM

Tags: vim, indentation

[image: non indented cursor]

See above picture. My cursor is on line 23 at the start of the line in normal mode. What is a quick command to begin inserting at the correct indentation level?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003393/vim-smart-indent-when-entering-insert-mode-on-blank-line) on Stack Overflow indicates that:

> '`cc`' will replace the contents of the current line and enter insert mode at the correct
>       indentation

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>o</kbd> will "open" a line above or below the current line, and at the correct indentation level.